# Can I run a node and aspnetcore in the same AppService?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have a nodejs application as the frontend and built my api in apsnetcore webapi. I'd like to run the api in the same domain i.e. /api. However I'm presented with runtime environment question when creating app service where I have to choose between dotnetcore and node. Anyone know how to get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you can from the link [here](https://medium.com/@tarkus/node-js-and-asp-net-side-by-side-8a2614460fb9) if you
"tweak URL Rewrite rules in web.config so that specific URLs are being handled by IISNode and the other ones by ASP.NET."